# ILMath function to arrange values given start, end and step size?

Tags: arrays, math, ilnumerics

I am trying to get an array linearly spaced given the step size.

For Example

```
arange(10,15,0.5) = 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5,15

arange(10, 15, 1) = 11, 12, 13, 14
```

There is linspace function that accepts only number of elements to be generated. Is there a way to provide step size instead of the number of elements?

For now, I calculate number of elements manually and use linspace to get the result.

Is there any straight to use api to get desired output? Thanks

Comment: is it intentional, that in your first example the upper bound is included in the output, but in the second example it is not?

Comment: sorry thats not intentional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ILArray<double> A = ILMath.vec<double>(10.0,0.5,15.0);
```

More array creation functions can be found in the [Array section of the documentation](http://ilnumerics.net/docs-core.html). A number of quick reference charts is also available:

ILNumerics' getting started: 
http://ilnumerics.net/media/oldres/img/ILNumerics_ArraysUsage.pdf

ILNumerics for Matlab users: 
http://ilnumerics.net/media/oldres/img/ILNumerics4MatlabUsers.pdf

Last but not least the class reference for all `ILMath` functions: 
http://ilnumerics.net/apidoc/?topic=html/Methods_T_ILNumerics_ILMath.htm